# Need graphical enhancement of two tikz flowcharts (in xetex)

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, flow-charts

I am new to tikz and I am looking for someone who would be so nice as to enhance/tweak my two tikz figures a little (which are created in xetex if this is important to note).

I did two flowcharts (also with the help of stackoverflow), see standalone code (MWEs) and figures below.

In Fig 1., I would like to ask if someone has an idea how to add some grayscale to the three boxes in the middle and a darker grey background for the top box?

In Fig. 2, I would like someone to

- a) adjust the whole figures so that the upper part is centred
- b) to make the two curly braces centred and bolder and
- c) that the single box in the middle is as dark grey as the top box in the
  Figure 1 (is going to be).

Would this be something someone would be willing to do? :)

**Fig. 1**

[image]

**Fig. 1 - code**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, tikzscale}
\usetikzlibrary{
shapes.geometric,
arrows,
arrows.meta,
calc,
positioning,
decorations.pathreplacing,
calligraphy, % had to be after lib. decorations.pathreplacing
bending} % add geometric shapes and arrows for flowcharts, plus calc package, positioning for relative positions
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{process2} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{process3} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape, node distance=2cm]
\centering\node (start) [process3] {Start};
\node (pro1) [startstop, below of=start] {Center*};
\node (pro2) [process, left=1.2cm of pro1] {Bla 1};
\node (pro3) [process, right=1.2cm of pro1, align=center] {Bla 2};
\node (pro4) [process2, below left= 0.3cm and -0.5cm of pro2, align=center] {Bla 3};
\node (pro5) [process2, below right= 0.3cm and -0.5cm of pro2, align=center] {Bla 4};
\node (pro6) [process2, below left= 0.3cm and -0.5cm of pro3, align=center] {Bla 5};
\node (pro7) [process2, below right= 0.3cm and -0.5cm of pro3, align=center] {Bla 6};
\node (OR) [right=0.6cm of pro4] {OR};

\draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (start);
\draw [arrow] (pro2.north) |- (start.west);
\draw [arrow] (pro3.north) |- (start.east);
\draw [arrow] (pro4.north) |- (pro2.west);
\draw [arrow] (pro5.north) |- (pro2.east);
\draw [arrow] (pro6.north) |- (pro3.west);
\draw [arrow] (pro7.north) |- (pro3.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Fig. 2**

[image]

**Fig. 2 - code**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, tikzscale}
\usepackage{paralist} % compactitem
\usetikzlibrary{
shapes.geometric,
arrows,
arrows.meta,
calc,
positioning,
decorations.pathreplacing,
calligraphy, % had to be after lib. decorations.pathreplacing
bending} % add geometric shapes and arrows for flowcharts, plus calc package, positioning for relative positions
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{process2} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{process3} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
transform shape,
node distance = 22mm and 11mm,
   box/.style = {shape=rectangle, draw, thin, 
                 minimum height=10mm, text width=32mm, align=center,
                 top color=#1!20, bottom color=#1!80,
                 anchor=south west
                 },
BC/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{ % Braces Calligraphic
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
        raise=#1,
              #2, % for mirroring of brace
        aspect=#3},
        very thick,
        pen colour={gray}
        },
]

\node (start) [process, align=center] {Bla 1};
\node (pro1) [process, right of=start, align=center, xshift=2cm] {Bla 2};
\node (pro2) [process, right of=pro1, align=center, xshift=2cm] {Bla 3};
\node (pro3) [process2, below of=start, align=center, yshift=-.5cm] {Bla 4};
\node (pro4) [process2, below of=pro1, align=center, yshift=-.5cm] {Bla 5};
\node (pro5) [process2, below of=pro2, yshift=-.5cm] {Bla 6};
\node (main) [startstop, below of=pro4, yshift=-.5cm] {Center*};
\node (pro6) [process3, below left=1cm and 1cm of main, align=center] {\parbox{.3\linewidth}{Bla 7,\begin{compactitem}\item Bla Bla \item Bla Bla \item Bla Bla\end{compactitem}}};
\node (pro7) [process3, below=1cm of main, align=center] {\parbox{.3\linewidth}{Bla 8,\begin{compactitem}\item Bla Bla \item Bla Bla \item Bla Bla \end{compactitem}}};
\node (pro8) [process3, below right=1cm and 1cm of main, align=center] {\parbox{.3\linewidth}{Bla 9,\begin{compactitem}\item Bla Bla \item Bla Bla \item Bla Bla \end{compactitem}}};
\node (pro9) [process3, right of=pro8, align=center, xshift=2cm] {\parbox{.3\linewidth}{Bla 10,\begin{compactitem}\item Bla Bla \item Bla Bla \item Bla Bla \end{compactitem}}};

\draw[-Stealth] (start) edge (pro3)
                (pro1.south)  edge (pro3) (pro1.south)  edge (pro5)
                (pro2.south)  edge (pro4) (pro2.south)  edge (pro5);                
% braces
\draw[BC=2mm/mirror/0.500] (pro3.south west) -- (pro5.south east);
\draw[BC=2mm/      /0.375] (pro6.north west) -- (pro9.north east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first graph:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, tikzscale}
\usetikzlibrary{
shapes.geometric,
arrows,
arrows.meta,
calc,
positioning,
decorations.pathreplacing,
calligraphy, % had to be after lib. decorations.pathreplacing
bending} % add geometric shapes and arrows for flowcharts, plus calc package, positioning for relative positions
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{process2} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{process3} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape, node distance=2cm]
\centering\node (start) [process3,fill=black!30] {Start}; % ============
\node (pro1) [startstop, below of=start,fill=black!10] {Center*}; % ============
\node (pro2) [process, left=1.2cm of pro1] {Bla 1};
\node (pro3) [process, right=1.2cm of pro1, align=center] {Bla 2};
\node (pro4) [process2, below left= 0.3cm and -0.5cm of pro2, align=center] {Bla 3};
\node (pro5) [process2, below right= 0.3cm and -0.5cm of pro2, align=center,fill=black!10] {Bla 4}; % ============
\node (pro6) [process2, below left= 0.3cm and -0.5cm of pro3, align=center,fill=black!10] {Bla 5}; % ============
\node (pro7) [process2, below right= 0.3cm and -0.5cm of pro3, align=center] {Bla 6};
\node (OR) [right=0.6cm of pro4] {OR};

\draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (start);
\draw [arrow] (pro2.north) |- (start.west);
\draw [arrow] (pro3.north) |- (start.east);
\draw [arrow] (pro4.north) |- (pro2.west);
\draw [arrow] (pro5.north) |- (pro2.east);
\draw [arrow] (pro6.north) |- (pro3.west);
\draw [arrow] (pro7.north) |- (pro3.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the second one:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, tikzscale}
\usepackage{paralist} % compactitem
\usetikzlibrary{
shapes.geometric,
arrows,
arrows.meta,
calc,
positioning,
decorations.pathreplacing,
calligraphy, % had to be after lib. decorations.pathreplacing
bending} % add geometric shapes and arrows for flowcharts, plus calc package, positioning for relative positions
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{process2} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{process3} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
transform shape,
node distance = 22mm and 11mm,
   box/.style = {shape=rectangle, draw, thin, 
                 minimum height=10mm, text width=32mm, align=center,
                 top color=#1!20, bottom color=#1!80,
                 anchor=south west
                 },
BC/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{ % Braces Calligraphic
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
        raise=#1,
              #2, % for mirroring of brace
        aspect=#3},
        very thick
        },
]

\node (start) [process, align=center] {Bla 1};
\node (pro1) [process, right of=start, align=center, xshift=2cm] {Bla 2};
\node (pro2) [process, right of=pro1, align=center, xshift=2cm] {Bla 3};
\node (pro3) [process2, below of=start, align=center, yshift=-.5cm] {Bla 4};
\node (pro4) [process2, below of=pro1, align=center, yshift=-.5cm] {Bla 5};
\node (pro5) [process2, below of=pro2, yshift=-.5cm] {Bla 6};
\node (main) [startstop, below of=pro4, yshift= 0cm, fill=black!30] {Center*};
\node (pro6) [process3, below =1cm of main,xshift=-6.3cm, align=center] {\parbox{.3\linewidth}{Bla 7,\begin{compactitem}\item Bla Bla \item Bla Bla \item Bla Bla\end{compactitem}}};
\node (pro7) [process3, below=1cm of main,xshift=-2.1cm, align=center] {\parbox{.3\linewidth}{Bla 8,\begin{compactitem}\item Bla Bla \item Bla Bla \item Bla Bla \end{compactitem}}};
\node (pro8) [process3, below=1cm of main,xshift=2.1cm, align=center] {\parbox{.3\linewidth}{Bla 9,\begin{compactitem}\item Bla Bla \item Bla Bla \item Bla Bla \end{compactitem}}};
\node (pro9) [process3, below=1cm of main,xshift=4.3cm, align=center, xshift=2cm] {\parbox{.3\linewidth}{Bla 10,\begin{compactitem}\item Bla Bla \item Bla Bla \item Bla Bla \end{compactitem}}};

\draw[-Stealth] (start) edge (pro3)
                (pro1.south)  edge (pro3) (pro1.south)  edge (pro5)
                (pro2.south)  edge (pro4) (pro2.south)  edge (pro5);                
% braces
\draw[BC=2mm/mirror/0.500] (pro3.south west) -- (pro5.south east);
\draw[BC=2mm/      /0.500] (pro6.north west) -- (pro9.north east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, AboAmmar. That´s exactly what I wanted!